# Deploy from BitBucket to Salesforce

Tags: deployment, git

I have SF project that its sources are stored in BitBucket repository. The question is how or which tools I can use if I want to run deployment that retrieve all the sources from BitBucket and run build to target SF org.

I try BitBucket Pipelines that allow to create CI/CD - when changes done for a branch then run auto deployment. But not clear if with this I can I run deployment per request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do manual deployment on request as well in Bitbucket pipeline.

Here's an example :

```
pipelines:  
  branches:
  #branch-01:
    #- step:
        #script:
          #- echo "Deploying branch-01 to Nowhere!" # delete this when all is good in auto-deploy 
  custom: # Pipelines that are triggered manually
    #Deploy_Manually_To_DevEnvironment:
    #- step:
        #script:
          #- echo "Deploying manually to Nowhere!" # delete this when all is good in auto-deploy
```

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/run-pipelines-manually-861242583.html

Comment: While this may seem to answer the question, your answer could have been improved by providing either a link or including more complete details/instructions on how to do what was asked. - from review queue

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful. I marked this as the best answer, as it more answering to the original question. Although cropredy suggestion tools are also great

Answer (score 7):

I'm not an employee of this vendor, but you can use [Gearset](https://gearset.com/) to easily deploy from both BitBucket, GitLab and GitHub to any SFDC org (and you can deploy from a feature org or scratch org to BitBucket, GitLab or GitHub).

Gearset offers CI job support - everything through point-and-click tools. Cost is reasonable, especially considering the value provided.

Comment: Our deployment master loves GearSet. I haven't personally used it, but they absolutely love how easy it is to use.

Comment: Thanks. Seems amazing tool. Can you recommend for additional alternative similar tools?

Comment: @lironc - we use Gearset and are quite happy with it - vendor has terrific support and is constantly improving the product.  Other tools are Blue Canvas, Copado and AutoRABIT

Comment: Can I submit my company's application (Snapshot - https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016YhyEAE) for consideration as well? Gives you similar deployment capabilities along with Org reporting.